# Error failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I have the data in the following format. I am using a neural network to predict three parameters downtime, latency and accuracy using neural network regression.

```
Node No Model    Technique   Downtime  Latency  Accuracy    
 1      Net     Repartition     0.90    31368.5  0.99   
 2      Net     Pause           0.10    21368.5  0.89   
 3      Mobile  Repartition     0.49    41368.5  0.79   
 4      Net     Pause           0.80    51368.5  0.98
```

Code

```
pre_norms = (predictors-predictors.mean()/predictors.std())
pre_norms.head()
predictors=data.drop(['Downtime','Latency','Accuracy'], axis = 1)
target=data[['Downtime', 'Latency', 'Accuracy']]
n_cols= pre_norms.shape[1]


def regression():
  model=Sequential()
  model.add(Dense(50, activation= 'relu',input_shape=(n_cols,)))
  model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))#hidden layer
  model.add(Dense(3))#output
  model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_squared_error')
  return model

model=regression()
model.fit(pre_norms, target,validation_split=.3,epochs=100,verbose=1)
```

Error

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type float).
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: your data looks like `pandas.DataFrame` how did you get error with `numpy.array` ? You should show FULL error - it shows which line makes problem.

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see what you have in variables. Maybe you have wrong values in your variables and alter it makes problem. For example in `predictors` you may have columns `Node`, `No Model` which has strings and converting it may gives problem. It may need preprocessing - convert string to numers - `Label Encoding` or `OneHot Encoding`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have missed one important step i.e. handling Text/Categorical Attributes. your `Model` and   `Technique` need to be converted to numbers. one of such way is

```
predictors_cat_converted=pd.get_dummies(predictors, prefix=['Model', 'Technique'])
```

now all the text has been transformed to numbers, you can run the model with this transformed data.

```
n_cols=predictors_cat_converted.shape[1]
model=regression()
model.fit(predictors_cat_converted, target,validation_split=.3,epochs=100,verbose=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't run your code so I created something similar and I get this error when `pre_norms` has values `NaN`.

I get `pre_norms` with `NaN` because `predictors` has columns `No_Model`,`Technique` which have strings and `predictors-predictors.mean()/predictors.std())` convert them to `NaN`

Solution could be removing columns `No_Model,Technique` but this create empty data - so it is useless.

I don't know you full code but you should check what you have in variables and if you have `NaN` then you have wrong calculations.